# Scaling canvas child to parents width and height as determined by the layout before adding the child

Tags: css, canvas, layout, html5-canvas

### Minimal Example in Codepen:

https://codepen.io/quaffpotion/pen/OJPqRgW (The green boxes are demonstrating the expected behavior while the behavior of the blue box is unexpected. You may need to resize your browser window to see that the blue box size will not always match the height and width of it's parent. I've added the padding for demonstration purposes)

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr) ) ;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
 }

 .box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;

 }

.a {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}

.k {
  grid-column: auto / span 3;
}

.g {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
}

.fillup {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  /* width: 100%; This causes the child element to be too big for the parent */
  border-radius: 5px;
  
}

.blue {
  background: skyblue;
}
.green {
  background: seagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b"><div class="fillup green">correctly fills parent</div></div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
  <div class="box g"><canvas class="fillup blue"></canvas></div>
  <div class="box h">H</div>
  <div class="box i"><div class="fillup green" >correctly fills parent</div></div>
  <div class="box j">J</div>
  <div class="box k">K</div>
  <div class="box l">L</div>
  <div class="box m">M</div>
</div>
```

### Problem Definition:

This is slightly different from the other scaling questions, I'll attempt to make it well defined.

I'm looking to achieve for canvas what `object-fit: fill` does to images. (Scales the width and height to match the parent, ignoring aspect ratio) Other ways to say this are the found below.

I want to be able to add a child element to a parent without changing the dimensions of the parent.

Said another way, the goal is to be able to follow these three steps:

1. You have a layout created using css grid of div elements. Let's say this includes `<div> Some Text </div>` which at a certain browser window size has dimensions 200 x 100 pixels.
2. You add a child element to the div from step 1. You add some styling to the child element.
3. When you reload the page and you make the browser have the same size as step 1 you see that the child element and the parent div both have size 200 x 100.

### Attempted Solutions:

- In the case where the child element is a `div` I can make it work, however it fails with an e.g. `canvas` element.
- Adding `width: 100%` to the styling of the canvas element **does** create an element that matches the size of it's parent however it **does not** match the size of it's parent in the original layout.
- Thanks to another source, I've added the following partial solution:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
fitToContainer(canvas);
function fitToContainer(canvas){
  // Make it visually fill the positioned parent
  canvas.style.width ='100%';
  canvas.style.height='100%';
  // ...then set the internal size to match
  canvas.width  = canvas.offsetWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but got one hint for you since you say it works with `div` but not `canvas`: By default, `canvas` is an inline-element, like `img`, and thus adds character white space afterwards. Maybe `canvas { display: block; }` is all you need?

Comment: I had not tried that yet, but still no luck. If it helps I think I'm looking to do for canvas what I believe `object-fit: fill` does for `img` elements. (The image is scaled in both directions to fit the dimensions of it's parent; the aspect ratio is not necessarily kept) I've tried explaining it a couple ways, maybe it's better to say I'd like to add a child element without changing the size of the parent.